# Find project files in RubyMine not working

Tags: rubymine

Every time I look for a file using the files finder console the file does not show up as a result of the search despite its existence in the project.

[image: Either the search is empty]

At certain point this feature was working but I may have change some configuration in Rubymine involuntary. Any help it's welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue already fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266391
Builds with the fix will be added to that issue so you can follow it.

As a workaround, please try invoking File - Invalidate Caches (still the issue might come back).